# How do I Seperate landlines from cell numbers

Tags: list

Hi i have a list of phone numbers that id like to send sms messages too but some of them are landlines and some are cell phone numbers is there a way to clean the list to tell which is which?

Comment: enter some examples of phone records, landline numbers and cell phone numbers

Answer (score 0):

There are services that will identify whether or not a phone number is a wireless or landline number.  When trying to determine whether a phone number is a wireless or a landline number you need to make sure number portability is taken into consideration.  Regarding North American phone numbers, some services only look at the exchange block (the first 7 digits) of the phone number to see if the phone number is assigned to a wireless or a landline block.  Since numbers can be ported (e.g. you can port your original landline number to a cell phone and vice versa) it's important to check the full 10 digit number to see whether it has been ported or not.

The company I work for, [PacificEast](http://www.pacificeast.com/), provides this in batch (you send the entire file) or via a web service (you query one phone number at a time) for US and Canadian phone numbers. Have a look at our [Line Identification Append](http://www.pacificeast.com/products/line_identification_append.aspx) service.  Other companies provide similar services as well.  Our [TeliSight](http://www.pacificeast.com/products/telisight.aspx) service will also provide the email address format you can use to send an email that will be converted to an SMS message for those North American carriers that support it.